# does eloquent cache results like $book->author?

Tags: laravel

Does eloquent send the same query multiple times when I do:

```
$author = $book->author;
$author = $book->author;
```

or does it cache the result itself? If yes, how long?

Comment: Is author a relation?

Answer (score 1):

Laravel load once relationship per instance of a class. If you want reload - write `$book->load('author')`. It's save to model relation. Read more https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: I recommend removing `per request`.  Per instance is correct.

Answer (score 1):

When you access a relation without parentheses like you are Laravel will first load the relation's data from your data base and then store the result in an internal property called `relations`. Every subsequent time you access that relation (again without parentheses) Laravel will read the data from there.

```
$book->author; // First time will trigger a query
$book->author; // Second and every subsequent access will load from relations property
```

This only lasts as long as the request/response lifecycle, it doesn't actually cache it in an any kind external store to make it persist between requests, but you can do that yourself using Laravel's caching mechanisms.

If you were to access your relation *with* parentheses, this would not be the case, Laravel would return to you a query builder object that you can use to further build a query. This is not cached in any way.

```
$book->author()->where(...)->first();
```

Take a look at Laravel's `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasAttributes::getRelationValue()` method which deals with loading relations when you try to access it as a property.

Answer (score 0):

When you load a relationship with Eloquent, it will cache it into a property named `relations`.

Therefore, if you do the following:

```
$author = $book->author;
```

And you look at the `$book` variable with `dd($book);`, your are going to see something like this:

```
Book {#312 ▼
  #appends: array:2 [▶]
  #fillable: array:7 [▶]
  #hidden: array:6 [▶]
  #with: array:2 [▶]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:11 [▶]
  #original: array:11 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: array:1 [▼
    "author" => Author {#441 ▼
      #appends: array:1 [▶]
      #fillable: array:9 [▶]
      #hidden: array:4 [▶]
      #with: array:2 [▶]
      #withCount: array:1 [▶]
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:13 [▶]
      #original: array:13 [▶]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: array:2 [▶]
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #visible: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    }
  ]
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}
```

If you want to reload the relationship, you have do use the fresh method:

```
$author = $book->fresh()->author;
```